# What is the difference between order and select when build dynamic Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, dynamic, lambda

This class use string parameter to order records 。It's work

```
public class Order
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderByDynamic<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string sortby)
    {
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(sortby);

        var result = typeof(Order)
            .GetMethod("OrderByDynamic_Private", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), property.PropertyType)
            .Invoke(null, new object[] { items, sortby});

        return (IEnumerable<T>)result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> OrderByDynamic_Private<T, TKey>(IEnumerable<T> items, string sortby)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

        Expression<Func<T, TKey>> property_access_expression =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TKey>>(
            Expression.Property(parameter, sortby),
            parameter);
            return items.OrderByDescending(property_access_expression.Compile());
        throw new Exception("Invalid Sort Direction");
    }
}
```

Then i want use string parameter to  determined column in select lambda expressions.
It's just replace all name "order" to "select" and replace return value to
items.Select(property_access_expression.Compile());

then i got Error "
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists" 
How to  solve  this error.

Comment: I can't understand your exact problem. Do you want to select fields dynamically via linq?

Comment: I want select fields dynamically via lambda expression

Comment: Can you give a desired output for example?

Comment: orderby Example: lambda expression ->r.OrderBy(x=>x.Name)                          
                when  use OrderByDynamic-> Order.OrderByDynamic(r,"Name")                      
 OrderByDynamic   second parameter can be any column  in r collection

Comment: OrderByDynamic will return collection same lambda expression r.OrderBy(x=>x.Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to select fields dynamically. I suggest you to do Order and Select with different methods. Here is how can you dynamically selects for given fields. It selects only given fields and prints default value for others. So it works for your use case.

```
class test
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Code + " " + Id;
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<test> list = new List<test>();

        list.Add(new test { Code = "1", Id = 5 });
        list.Add(new test { Code = "2", Id = 6 });
        list.Add(new test { Code = "3", Id = 7 });
        list.Add(new test { Code = "4", Id = 8 });

        list.AsQueryable()
             .Select(DynamicSelect<test>("Id"))
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}


public static Expression<Func<T, T>> DynamicSelect<T>(string fields)
{
    var members = fields.Split(',').Select(f => f.Trim());
    var targetType = typeof(T);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "x");
    var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
    var target = Expression.Constant(null, targetType);

    foreach (var name in members)
    {
        var targetMember = Expression.PropertyOrField(target, name);
        var sourceMember = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, name);
        bindings.Add(Expression.Bind(targetMember.Member, sourceMember));
    }

    var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(targetType), bindings);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(body, parameter);
}
```